# Testing Angular 1.6 with Jest return async callback was not invoked

Tags: angularjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test a Angular 1.6 service with Jest, but I got error everytime, someone faced this problem ? (I'm not using setTimeout in my service as you can see below)

**Error**

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

**Test Specs**

```
describe('Fail Cases', () => {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('marvel'))
  let _marvelservice
  beforeEach(inject((MarvelService) => {
    _marvelservice = MarvelService
  }))

  test('should return false when user do not put the id for details correctly', (done) => {
    _marvelservice.getDetail()
      .catch((err) => {
        expect(err.xhrStatus).toBe('error')
        done()
      })
  })
})
```

**Marvel Service**

```
(() => {
  angular.module('marvel')
    .factory('MarvelService', ($http, $q, Config) => {
      /**
       * Get details from a characters by consulting the Marvel API.
       * @return {Object} Doc with detail character recovered.
       */
      function getDetail (id) {
        const urlAddress = `/${id}`
        return request(urlAddress, 'GET', { ts: 1, apikey: `${Config.MARVEL.PUBLIC_KEY}`, hash: `${Config.MARVEL.MD5}` })
      }

      /**
       * Responsible for request.
       * @return {Object} Doc with the returned promise.
       */
      function request (path, method, querystring) {
        const options = {
          method,
          url: `${Config.MARVEL.URL}${path}`,
          params: querystring
        }

        return $http(options)
          .then(success => { return success.data }, (err) => {
            return err
          })
      }

      return {
        getDetail
      }
    })
})()
```

Comment: maybe the timeout is a default value that you can override

Comment: This was discussed numerous times and isn't specific to Jest. $q promises are synchronous and don't require `done`, but promise chain won't be executed without $rootScope.$digest(). I'd suggest to go with https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers

Comment: @JohnKane I've try `jest.setTimeout = 10000` but I got the same error above

Comment: wouldnt it be: jest.setTimeout(10000);

Comment: @JohnKane sorry my mistake, but the error persist anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807119/jasmine-unit-tests-not-waiting-for-promise-resolution

Comment: @estus I'll take a look at this lib now

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that in your `test` block, `done()` is never being run, most likely because the code inside the `.catch()` callback is never being run. This is likely because your API request is succeeding instead of failing. You should make the request fail to reach the `.catch()` block: either by performing a request that your API will throw an error at, or by spying on the request and forcing it to fail, like so:

```
test('should return false when user do not put the id for details correctly', (done) => {
    // You must inject $q somewhere
    spyOn(_marvelservice, 'getDetail').and.returnValue($q.reject());

    _marvelservice.getDetail()
      .catch((err) => {
        expect(err.xhrStatus).toBe('error');
        done();
      });
  });
```